# Adding elements to numpy 1D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array (a). How can I add two elements in it?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([5,6,7])

b = 3
c = 4

result = np.hstack((b,c,a))
print result
```

Works using answer from @BHAT IRSHAD

I have to do it to use with np.savetxt; I wan to write the result as one row. But could not.

```
np.savetxt('fo.txt', result, delimiter = ',', fmt = '%s')
```

Comment: What does it do instead?  Put one number of each line?  Try making `result` a 2d array (e.g. `result.reshape((1,-1))`).  That should put all your values on one line (ie. 1 row per line).

Comment: @hpaulj It wrote data into column instead of row. Is there better way to do it from the beginning, i.e., not using hstack?

Comment: `np.savetxt(s,np.concatenate(([b],[c],a)).reshape(1,-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.hstack` takes only one argument and you are passing three, so `result = np.hstack((b,c,a))` will work.

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.array([5,6,7])
>>> b = 3
>>> c = 4
>>> np.hstack((b,c,a))
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks +1, can you see my edited question for a small further help?

Comment: You can use `newline` instead of `delimiter` as `np.savetxt('fo.txt', result, newline = '\t', fmt = '%s')` or use `reshape` to save array in a single row as `np.savetxt('fo.txt', result.reshape(1, len(result)), delimiter = ',', fmt = '%s')`.

Comment: nope, what if I have to write other rows below the results?